# How to test video file upload in cypress?

Tags: cypress

This forum has been really useful since I am new to automation and Cypress. I am also facing a problem while trying to upload file to application.

I used the below code in command.js:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('uploadFile', { prevSubject: true }, (subject, fileName, fileType = '') => {
    cy.fixture(fileName,'binary').then(content => {
      return Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob(content, fileType).then(blob => {
        const el = subject[0];
        const testFile = new File([blob], fileName, {type: fileType});
        const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();

        dataTransfer.items.add(testFile);
        el.files = dataTransfer.files;
        cy.wrap(subject).trigger('change', { force: true });
      });
    });
  });
```

And then below code in test:

```
const fileName = 'comp-test-malte.mp4';
const fileType = 'video/mp4';
cy.get('input[type=file]').uploadFile(fileName, fileType);
```

This is working half way for me as it shows uploading 0%, but getting the below error from the database and the file is not uploaded:

"Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in put at index 0: Expected Blob or File."

Kindly help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, it seems **[Cypress.io](https://www.cypress.io/)** doesn't support this feature, ***according to these sources:***

**[Source 1](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html)**

**[Source 2](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4938)**

**[Source 3](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/170)**

You could use a ***[cypress-file-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload)*** **npm package** as a workaround though!

In this **[thread comment](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/170#issuecomment-566700991)** you might find a proper workaround for it like so:

```
// sample code found in the thread
.fixture('bear.mp4', 'binary')
  .then(Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob)
  .then(fileContent => {
    cy.get('#upload-video').upload({
      fileContent,
      fileName: 'bear.mp4',
      mimeType: 'video/mp4',
      encoding: 'utf8'
    })
})
```

For more details, **[check this repository](https://github.com/abramenal/cypress-file-upload)**.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I tried the above approach but again facing another issue :(

Uncaught (in promise) Event {isTrusted: true, type: "error", target: null, currentTarget: null, eventPhase: 0, …}

Have any idea??

Comment: @CuriousSoul230 have you tried any solutions in the comment thread link that I shared with you? You could also try [this solution](https://github.com/abramenal/cypress-file-upload). Let me know what you have tried so I can assist you better

Comment: sample code u provided modified a little worked for me...found that in the thread :) (I somehow missed it last time)

cy.fixture(fileName, 'binary')
            .then(Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob)
            .then(fileContent => {
            cy.get('input[type=file]').upload({
                fileContent,
                fileName,
                mimeType,
                encoding: 'utf8'
            })
        })

Comment: Now this worked for the video file...I have another scenario to upload a json file as well...But same approach is not working there :(
Getting the below error;
Label Configuration must be a JSON file.Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: @CuriousSoul230 could you edit my reply & add the modification that worked for you? That way other developers can use it as reference in the future. Please it solves the issue, make sure to accept my answer. About the next question, could you provide me [minimal, reproducible  example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Without that from the top of my head, I would try to parse the JSON file

Comment: I am trying to parse the JSON and fix the problem, it hasn't worked so far...I will try some more aproaches and stil if it doesnt work have to come up with minimal reproducable example. I have to go through the doc to understand how to produce that :(
Thanks for all the help so far... :)

Comment: I am back with the same issue. 
`it('Uploading Configuration', () => {
        const fileName = 'Config.json';
        const mimeType = 'application/json';        
        cy.fixture(fileName)
            .then(JSON.stringify())
            .then(jsonStr => {
            cy.get('input[type=file]').upload({
                jsonStr,
                fileName,
                mimeType,
                encoding: 'utf-8'
            })
        })
        });`
This is the error I am getting now.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'timeout' of undefined
:(

Comment: Can you share your repo link? I might take a look during the weekend.

Comment: This issue is resolved for me. The below code was used to upload a json file.
it('Uploading label Configuration', () => {
        const fileName = 'config.json';
        const mimeType = 'application/json';
        cy.fixture(fileName).then(fileJson => {
            const fileContent = JSON.stringify(fileJson);
            cy.get('input[type="file"]').upload({ fileContent, fileName, mimeType});
        });
});

Answer (score 0):

You can use cypress-upload-file library to help you.

First install the dependence using terminal in the directory of your project:

```
npm install --save-dev cypress-upload-file
```

And then do:

```
    describe("Upload the file", () => {
  it("Upload the file and assert the name of the file uploaded", () => {
    cy.visit("https://your-url.example");

    const fileName = "bear.mp4";
    const fileType = "video/mp4";
    const selector = "#upload-video;

    uploadFile(selector, fileName, fileType);
  });
});
```

Hope this works for you! Best regards.